# error loading SQL server PHP extension on IIS

Tags: javascript, php, sql-server, iis

So I'm new to this IIS, the problem I had is
I get PHP Fatal error:  Call to undefined function **sqlsrv_connect()**

And I found that many people have some issues and none of the solution work for me.

What I've done :

1. copying the driver to ext
2. done checking ts or nts //i got ts
3. phpmyadmin / mysql server work just fine
4. I've add the extension inside **php.ini** too
5. I didn't found any extension mentioning mssql//they said I've to remove this when I want to add the extension

PHP Version 5.6.40/
x64/
SQL Server 2017/
Driver downloaded : 3.2 (56_ts), 3.0(54_ts) : both didnt work

Comment: PHP 5.6 is dead. http://php.net/supported-versions.php You have to upgrade to a supported version and then see if the issue remains.

Comment: alright, gotta try dat out